# Is there an easy way to find which part of the code not closing the file

Tags: python, file

I have a large program with large amount of code. And it s is opening the file but not closing it.

#### Question:

Is there an easy way to find out where this happening?

#### More Details:

OS - Linux
Python - 2.7

Why this is important? Imagine the situation:

```
df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       157G   39G  110G  27% /
```

110 G Available. Let's create large file

```
fallocate -l 10G large_file.csv
```

Now 100 G available

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       157G   49G  100G  34% /
```

lets'write the program that opens the file and run it:

```
import time
f = open('large_file.csv')
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except:
    pass
```

While this is running, let's delete the file:

```
rm large_file.csv
```

Checking space:

```
df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       157G   49G  100G  34% /
```

You see it's still `100G` available.

So the question is how to easily find this type of issues in the large program?

Comment: That is what the `lsof` command is for.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I know what process doing it. I need to find what part of the program is doing it. sorry if my question is not clear.

Comment: Just use the `with` statement or `try+finally` to deal with files so you never forget to close them.

Comment: how does the file name get into the code, is it read from a config file? passed as a program argument ? straight up hard coded ? this looks as simple as finding where a certain name is being used

Comment: How many `open()` calls are we talking about here? *How large* a project is this?

Comment: @Paulo Scardine I know how to properly deal with files, I need to find where this is happening

Comment: You seem to say that your process `opens` a non-existant file, and you complain about "still 100 GB" available (just like before you created the large file). It would probably help if you made this consistent.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: You can unlink an open file; the file still exists *until closed*. What is gone is the directory entry. *This is by design*.

Comment: note: this might be just nitpicking, but in general you can only find the part that is *opening* the file, not the one which *isn't closing* it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: traditionally you can unlink an open file in unix-like systems, but not on Windows for example - so it is platform dependent.

Comment: @PauloScardine: `df -h` is also platform dependent, this is a UNIX (like) OS the OP is using. In fact, they state they are using Linux, explicitly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I know, the behavior described is only possible when using an unix-like OS - I meant to make the statement more precise, not to disagree with it.

Comment: @Vor: the correct way to fix the problem is not detecting where it occurs (because it is run-time dependent and the bug can show itself in another place and occasion), is to locate every instance of `open` and surround it with a `with` statement of `try-finally`.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine What if you using some 3-d party libraries? the only way I see is to go through each line with `pdb`. But I was hoping there is an easier way of doing it.

Comment: Perhaps you could replace the default `open` in the `__builtin__` module with a wrapper that keeps track of where they occur.

Comment: @Vor: you can replace the default `open` on the `__builtin__` module as suggested by martineau to raise an exception, catch the exception and use the `inspect` module to search the AST from the traceback to see if the `open` call is preceded by a `with` or `try/finally` block (`getouterframes`), if not you can locate the relevant blocks of code. It is an interesting problem but unfortunately I lack the time to post a proper answer.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine thank you, I'll try to follow your suggestions

Comment: following @MartijnPieters suggestion about using `lsof`, I've come up with a simple for loop, that I'm running as `cron` job until I finnished Paulo Scradine suggestion. Here is the for loop: ``for i in `ls -ld /proc/*/fd/* | grep '(deleted)'`; do > $i; done;``

Comment: BTW, I remember reading somewhere that cpython is garanteed to close all file handles when garbage collecting, so check if your problem is really due to python code. MySQL is a known offender here (for deleting open file handlers), so if there is a MySQL database involved I would bet on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember reading somewhere that cpython is guaranteed to close all file handles when garbage collecting, so unless you are segfaulting I guess your python program is not the culprit (or there is a C module misbehaving and this answer is worthless). MySQL is a known offender here (for deleting open file handlers), so if there is a MySQL database involved I would bet on it.

That said, you can monkey-patch `__builtin__.open` as suggested by martineau to raise an exception, catch the exception and use the inspect module to search the traceback and check if the open call is inside a with statement or try/finally block. The following example is very crude but I hope it can get you started:

```
#test.py
import foo

_old_open = open  # original function
# monkey-patch
def _new_open(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        raise(Exception('dummy'))
    except Exception as e:
        import sys
        check_call(*sys.exc_info())
    return _old_open(*args, **kwargs)
__builtins__.open = _new_open


def check_call(e_type, e_value, tb):
    import inspect, sys
    # restore patch to avoid infinite recursion
    __builtins__.open = _old_open  
    try:
        stack = inspect.getouterframes(tb.tb_frame)
        frame_info = inspect.getframeinfo(stack[1][0])
        if frame_info.code_context[0].strip()\
                     .startswith('with '):
            return
        sys.stderr.write(
           "DEBUG: open call outside with block at "
           "{f.filename}, line {f.lineno}\n"
           .format(f=frame_info)
        )
    finally:
        __builtins__.open = _new_open


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo.baz('a.txt')
    foo.bar('a.txt')

# foo.py
def bar(fname):
    f = open(fname, 'w')

def baz(fname):
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write('dummy!')

# result:
# DEBUG: open call outside with block at 
# /path/to/foo.py, line 13
```